# Good backup solution for windows webserver 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

What I basically want to do in order to backup the website running on my webserver:

- create a dump of the mysql database
- copy / zip a certain folder containing the website in a directory
- zip the directory with the backuped website and the dump
- transfer it to another server or another HD or something like that

How can I automate this process to be executed every day at midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should have what you need.

[IIS 7 Backup Strategy](https://serverfault.com/questions/9380/iis-7-backup-strategy)

[MySQL database backup over network](https://serverfault.com/questions/30543/mysql-database-backup-over-network)

All you should need after that is a good understanding of robocopy and scheduler syntax.